# Conditionally set an attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to conditionally set an attribute using jQuery? For example, I want to simplify this:

```
$(element).val('99');

if ([condition]) {
    $(element).attr('myAttr', 1);
}
```

This works, but forces me break the chaining of method calls. Instead, I would prefer something like this:

```
$(element).val('99').attr('myAttr', 1, [condition]);
```

So that the attribute is only set if the condition is true. How would I do this?

Comment: just for fun `$(element).val('99').filter(function () {
    return [condition]; //return true if conditon is true else false
}).attr('myAttr', 1);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you could use:

```
$(element).val('99').attr('myAttr',[condition] ? 1 : $(element).attr('myAttr'));
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n7hXu/1/)**

**Option 2,** just: `$(element).val('99').attr('attr',[condition] ? 1 : undefined)`.

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n7hXu/)**

*Please notice that this option 2, as @FrédéricHamidi [**mentioned**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028806/conditionally-set-an-attribute-using-jquery/19028862?noredirect=1#comment28117998_19028862), might break the chain in older versions of jQuery. But works from jQuery 1.7.2*

Comment: the OP never said that the value will be `0` if the condition is false

Comment: @ArunPJohny Then he is welcomed to change it to the wanted value.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, true, I posted an example. `[condition]` is not proper syntax either, just to help OP to understan using OP's idea

Comment: However this would always render the attribute, just with a different value. I'm looking for a way to omit the attribute altogether if [condition] is not met.

Comment: @matk see Frédéric Hamidi's answer

Comment: @Sergio, your last edit is clever: passing `undefined` to `attr()` that way actually switches it to its getter form. It does the job, but will break chaining (you cannot chain after a getter).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, didn't think of that. Maybe not so clever in the end... Will remove that. Thank you.

Comment: I just tested @Sergio's last edit, and it actually seems to work: $('#btn').val('zzz').attr('data-x', undefined).attr('data-y', 'yyy') will give me e.g. [input type="button" id="btn" value="zzz" data-y="yyy"]! I also thought that this would break chaining, so how reliable is this?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, this seems to work `$('div').attr('attr', undefined).text('bar')` -> jsfiddle.net/n7hXu/2

Comment: @Sergio, indeed it seems to work from jQuery 1.7 onwards. I guess they changed the argument detection pattern to support this case (I will double-check). So this is a valid use after all :)

Comment: @Sergio, I double-checked, `attr()` now delegates to the internal `access()` method and uses `arguments.length` to determine if it should run its getter or setter form. Therefore, passing `undefined` results in a no-op setter that supports chaining. You should reinstate this solution in your answer, I think it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you both for your insight. I'll accept Sergio's answer because it offers the conciseness I was after, but props to you, @FrédéricHamidi, for your input. So the "now" in "attr() now delegates" refers to >= jQuery 1.7?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, just did that. Thank you again for the valuable input!

Comment: @matk, to somewhere between 1.6.4 and 1.7.2 (I cannot test intermediate versions from jsFiddle).

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to reset the attribute value when the condition is false, you can use [the form of `attr()` that takes a function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr):

```
$(element).val("99").attr("myAttr", function() {
    if (condition) {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Not returning anything from the function (or returning `undefined`, which is equivalent) will leave the attribute value unchanged.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - would this not suffer from the same problem you mentioned in your other answer, in that it would break chaining for everything that comes after this call to attr(...)?

Comment: @natk, nope, because even if the function doesn't return anything, `attr()` is still in its setter form, and therefore chainable (it will always return a jQuery object, not the attribute value like its getter form does).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var attrValue=[condition] ? 1 : 0;
$(element).val('99').attr('myAttr',attrValue);
```

If you want **chaining** then you can `chain` in condition like,

```
if ([condition]) {
    $(element).val('99').attr('myAttr', 1);
}
else
{
    $(element).val('99');
}
```

Try this,

```
$inpt=$(element).val('99');
if(true)
{
    $inpt.attr('myAttr',1);// use $inpt for setting attribute
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6HjC/)

Comment: This would always render the attribute, just with a different value. I'm looking for a way to omit the attribute altogether if [condition] is not met.

Comment: thanks, but this code is now _identical_ to the code in my original question that I'm trying to improve.